# Is using the completed type name in code is faster than a using directive for the whole namespace

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, dllimport, using-statement

For the best website performance is using: (for example)

```
Telerik.Web.UI.RadChart ResultChart = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadChart();
```

Is faster than :

```
using Telerik.Web.UI;
```

and

```
RadChart ResultChart = new RadChart();
```

and what if i used the `using` directive in many modules in ASP.net page, does the compiler use it once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference. The compiled IL will contain the fully qualified name every time the type needs to be used.

The `using` statement just makes your code file shorter and easier to read.

The number of times a directive appears in your code also makes no difference - just the fact that the assembly that it is in is referenced by the project is enough.

Comment: Even in .ASPX:
`<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>`?

Comment: @Ala - Yes. This is just a way for you to be able to use `telerik:` in your markup.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

`using` statements makes your code short and more readable. There is no problem if you use it in many modules. Same IL (Intermediate Language) code created for both version. You can check it these two piece of code and their IL codes;

```
using System;

namespace Programs
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Foo";
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string s)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Foo"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

---

```
namespace Programs
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.String s = "Foo";
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] string s)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Foo"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: Like many of your answers, you seem to paraphrase previous answers and not really adding much. How come?

Comment: @Oded I never give an answer based on pervious answer(s). When I see the the question and If I know the answer, I prefer to add quick answer (not best quality of course). After that, I update it regularly for explaining my full answer. You are one of my favorite user in SO and actually, hearing this from you, breaks my heart.

Comment: I apologize if my conclusions are wrong. The few answers I have seen from you looked like they were directly rephrasing other answers.

Comment: Sometimes people can answer the close answers each other nearly close times. I asked a [question about that issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94004/same-answers-should-be-deleted-in-stack-overflow), and ChrisF wrote a [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94004/same-answers-should-be-deleted-in-stack-overflow#comment235982_94004) about it which I agree with him. But hey, not a big deal ;)